# Bidirectional buck boost converter

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, converter, buck-boost, bidirectional

I am searching for a bidirectional buck boost converter evaluation board for charging and discharging the batteries.

- Input= upto 30V DC
- Output= upto 10V to 20V DC
- Current= less than 10A

I always find bidirectional buck boost controllers (ISL81601EVAL1Z, DC2719A) rather than converter. I use a microcontroller to generate the PWM signal to control duty cycle of the converter there by maintaining constant output voltage.

So, if I buy the buck boost controller can I control it with a microcontroller?

When I read its user guide it says no words about using a microcontroller for generating PWM.

Can anyone please help me in this?

If you know any boards please inform me.

Comment: Controller usually generate pwm (or frequency for resonant topologies) dependent signal basing of feedback voltage (s). Controller doesn't contain power stage - it only generates needed signal. You can create such feedback path, that You will be able to control it using microcontroller, but in linear, not pwm

Comment: can you explain me clearly as I dnt have much experience in this area.

Comment: The job of the controller is to control the voltage. It generates the PWM itself. If you want to generate the PWM and control the voltage with a micro you can. You will need to use a gate driver to switch the FET on and off. Shopping questions are off topic here. But in that case you don't need the controller at all.

Comment: Power stage (usually transistors) need some signal to be controlled with. These signals can be created using microcontroller, dedicated controller or anything else - as long as it works it doesnt matter. Althrough - microcontoller needs to convert analog signal to digital one, process it and so on. It takes time, and to keep good regulation fast response in needed. This is when dedicated controllers come into play - they operate on analog signal and thus are very fast (sometimes too fast and they oscillate)

Comment: If You want to control voltages/currents using microcontroller - simplest thing is to generate reference voltages from it and inject them into feedback using opamps

Answer (score 1):

Usually,

- "converter" means the chip has integrated MOSFETs,
- "controller" means it doesn't, and you have to add MOSFETs external to the chip.

For 10A current you won't find many converter chips, you'll have to use a controller with external FETs. This is a more convenient option since you can optimize FET choice for your voltage and current rather than having only one choice of FETs inside the chip.

> I use Microcontroller to generate the PWM signal to control duty cycle of the converter there by maintaining constant output voltage.

That's usually extra work because the inductor current depends on PWM value and a small variation in PWM value results in huge variation in inductor current.

For example if you have a buck with 10mOhms FETs and a 10mOhm inductor, and 30V input, then a 0.1% variation in duty cycle corresponds to 30mV across 20mOhm, ie a variation in average inductor current of 1.5A. And a 8-bit PWM, which gives a 1LSB variation of 1/256, results in 5.8A current variation per LSB. So you need a PWM with lots of bits to get just the right PWM value, but that will require a ludicrous clock frequency like 2^10 times PWM frequency, so in practice you need to dither it, which means more headache and at least one software control loop iteration per cycle, in real time.

This setup requires a fast accurate software control loop and ADCs, tight timing, and any bug will destroy the MOSFETs. Using the debug probe will also pause your micro, stop the feedback loop, and destroy your MOSFETs. For safety you will need at least a fast current sense comparator (handling both current directions) that feeds directly into the micro's PWM peripheral to shuts down PWM and disable the FET if maximum inductor current is exceeded. So you need a micro with "motor control" feature or similar, that has a PWM controller with this special "fault" input that stops everything. Note that stopping the PWM is not enough, you have to make sure it stops in a state where the top FETs are OFF, otherwise it will short either the input or the output supply.

A much simpler option is to not generate the PWM with the micro but to use a buck-boost controller chip that regulates current automatically. This can use any control scheme, can be hysteretic, current mode, whatever. Then you use the micro to set the current. You can use a DAC, or you can go low-tech and just have the buck-boost always operate at its maximum efficiency current and turn it on and off with a PWM. This is quite simple and safe. If you don't want a software bug to destroy your board, you can add voltage comparators to shut it down in case of input/output overvoltage.

I've done this with a bidirectional buck that acts as a buck to charge a battery, and a boost when the current flows in the other direction from the battery to the power rail. I've used a simple hysteretic control with a comparator that monitors current on a low side shunt resistor. Adding a bit of offset to the comparator threshold via mcu gpio and some resistors, I can set it to pump current in either direction. It always operates at the same current, and the whole thing is enabled/disabled by a low frequency PWM from the micro.

In battery charging mode it is a switchmode constant current source, since inductor current is monitored by the hysteresis comparator that drives the FETs. So, average battery charging current is proportional to the PWM value. In reality, it delivers pulsed current, with a cap on the output to smooth it out. The micro has an internal comparator that stops the PWM peripheral in case of output overvoltage which would happen if the battery was disconnected.

In battery discharging mode, it is also a constant current source that feeds the power rail from the battery. Rail voltage is regulated by the micro, and the control loop is simple since the power rail has large capacitors which provide a large time constant, and it's a +24V rail which will tolerate +/- a few volts of ripple without any trouble since it feeds other DC-DCs anyway. So the micro has plenty of time to adjust the PWM value before the voltage drifts out of spec.

It works nicely, it's cheap, reliable, and efficient.

Comment: so you used this method with the available evaluation boards or you built a separate bidirectional buck boost converter on breadboard for your use.

Comment: I built it on a pcb, it was part of a larger design.

Comment: Ok I just need a module I dnt have much time to design on PCB.